# Dynamically loading html into AngularJs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I have some problem getting jQuery which i'm more familiar with to load html with ajax then add this to the view. The template is already loaded then I need to get some data externaly through ajax and put it inside element. But AngularJs runs before all this, I want it to wait until all data is loaded.

Edit: Just to clarify, here is the code, I run the custom.js.

```
 $stateProvider


    // Companyresults
    .state('companyresults', {
        url: "/companyresults.html",
        templateUrl: "views/companyresults.html",            
        data: {pageTitle: 'Dashboard', pageSubTitle: 'statistics & reports'},
        controller: "CompanyResultsController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                    files: [
                            '../../../assets/admin/layout3/scripts/custom.js',
                        'js/controllers/CompanyResultsController.js'
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        }
    });
```

And..

```
     'use strict';

    MetronicApp.controller('CompanyResultsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {   
       // initialize core components
       Metronic.initAjax();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I will recommend you to read [__“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/14994393#14994393)

Comment: I would recommend loading AJAX data via Angular's $http service.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ng-app` directive to launch the app you should run `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);` when you think your document is ready (e.g. in jQuery callback);

Take notice that you can also use jQuery Ajax functions within Angular, but you need to wrap any changes in DOM with `$scope.$apply` to make Angular aware of jQuery's actions):

```
// within Angular controller
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // any DOM changes
    });
});
```

But consider (this would be the best solution) embedding ajax code in Angular, `$http` service doesn't differ too much from `jQuery.ajax`, especially if you're familiar with jQuery Promises.

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom directive and call your jquery plugin inside link function

```
  var directiveModule = angular.module("directiveModule", []);

    directiveModule.directive('wrapJqueryplugin', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs) {        
    *********your jquery code ****************
});
```

and in your view

```
    <wrap-jqueryplugin>
***    any Dom Elements ***
    </wrap-jqueryplugin>
```